# Unabe to create Search Service Application

Tags: 2010, search, service-application

When creating a new Search Service Application the job seems to stop half way through.

The search service application is created but displays an error in the Service Application page and the search service application proxy is not created.
[image]

The search account I’ve created is a configured managed account and I’m confident I’ve granted the account the correct SQL permissions(probably given it more than it needs now).
[image]

I'm hoping this is easy and I;m missing something simple.
Thanks

Comment: A good way to start is to look at your logging, which you maybe allready did.

I use this tool to have a better overview of my logs.

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your replies.

Initially I thought this was just a problem with creating the search service application. I soon discovered I couldn't deploy service applications or solutions. The job would appear to run but never actually carry out the job.

I should note that the farm has been built in hyperV.

The search service was finally provisioned. The search service application displayed an error indicating that the Search Service could not connect to the machine running the Search Administration Component. It looks like the SharePoint Config DB thinks that this component is running on another server or possibly when the snapshots were restored putting the Config DB in an inconsistent state.

This is why I mentioned the farm is built in hyperV. I don't recall creating or rolling back to snapshots but the farm servers were built using templates. In short I rebuilt the farm and I'm back working. I'm not convinced the inconsistent Config DB was caused by rollbacks but either way BE WARNED!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I think you need to delete and recreate the service.

Maybe you will have problem with the process of delete too, if so I suggest to you too read this post: http://salvatoredifaziosharepoint.blogspot.com/2012/02/cannot-delete-search-service.html

Comment: Thanks Salvatore. I've already deleted the service application and recreated it.

Comment: have you successfully created the service?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you would have already checked your SQL server permissions and Collation is - Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS

I had this problem once.

Answer (score 0):

If SharePoint thinks that the search is running on a server that you don't have in the farm anymore, you could try moving search to a server that actually is part of your farm.

http://iedaddy.com/2011/10/sharepoint-2010-migrating-search-admin-to-different-servers-in-the-farm/